# Initialization of 'g' and 'graph' vars on server start

Tags: titan, gremlin

Upon starting gremlin console, the `g` and `graph` objects aren't being automatically instantiated. From reading it seems that I don't have something configured correctly to allow for this during startup.

I've checked my gremlin-server.yaml file, which includes

```
graphs: {
  graph: conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb.properties}
```

I'm able to manually create the objects in the console, so it does work

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb.properties');
==>standardtitangraph[com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement();
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@433b546f
gremlin> g = graph.traversal(standard());
==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
```

Is there something else I'm missing? I found [this issue](https://github.com/jbmusso/gremlin-javascript/issues/21) logged on the `gremlin-javascript` project, but am still stuck. I think my problem is with my configuration on the server and not my implementation of `gremlin-javascript`.

Ultimately I'm trying to traverse using `gremlin-javascript`, but I'm forced to create 'graph' and 'g' each time (slow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior when starting the Gremlin console, unless you start it with an init script that does this for you:

```
// scripts/initMyGraph.groovy

graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb.properties')
g = graph.traversal(standard())
```

Then start the console with:

```
bin/gremlin.sh scripts/initMyGraph.groovy
```

`Graph` and `Traversal` objects will be accessible as `graph` and `g` variables in the console, respectively.